# Find the associated matrix to a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, polynomials, linear-transformations

Let $D:\mathbb{P}_3[x]\to\mathbb{P}_2[x]$ be the linear transformation $f(x)\rightarrow f'(x)$. I.e, the derivative of $f(x)$. $\mathbb{P}_n[x]$ denotes the vector space of real polynomials of degree less or equal to $n$.

1. Find the associated matrix to $D$ with respect to the bases: $$\mathcal{B}=\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}  ~~\text{and}~~  \mathcal{C}=\{1,x,x^2\}$$
2. Find the associated matrix to $D$ with respect to the bases $\mathcal{B}'$ of $\mathbb{P}_3[x]$ and $\mathcal{C}'$ of $\mathbb{P}_2[x]$
   $$\mathcal{B}'=\{x^3+1,x^2+x,x^2-x,x^3-1\}$$ and $$\mathcal{C}'=\{\frac{1}{2}x(x+1),1-x^2,\frac{1}{2}x(x-1)\}.$$

I solved part 1. and I obtained  the associated matrix, which is $$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 2 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 3
\end{pmatrix}$$

However, I couldn't solve part 2. I don't really know how to proceed. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know how to find the change-of-basis matrices from $\mathcal B'$ to $\mathcal B$, and from $\mathcal C$ to $\mathcal C'$?

Comment: If $B$ and $C$ are the matrices of the respective basis changes then by multiplying  $B^{-1}$ the old components of an element of ${\mathbb P}_3[x]$ you get itsnnew components, and similar in the codomain. So $$C^{-1}f(p)=C^{-1}f(BB^{-1}p),$$ it is here that you can see that the product $$C^{-1}fB,$$ connects the new versions of the polynomials $p$ and $f(p)$

Comment: @Bungo, yes, I have found the change of basis matrices, but I'm not sure how to use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elements order in both new basis determine their associated matrices.

Since for $\mathcal B$ we have
$$1\mapsto 1+x^3,$$
$$x\mapsto x+x^2,$$
$$x^2\mapsto -1+x^2,$$
$$x^3\mapsto -1+x^3,$$
then
$$B=
\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1&0&0&-1\\0&1&-1&0\\0&1&1&0\\1&0&0&1
\end{array}\right).$$
And working similarly for $\mathcal C$ its matrix is
$$C=
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0&1&0\\1/2&0&-1/2\\1/2&-1&1/2
\end{array}\right).$$
Hence by the use of $C^{-1}DB$ you will get the matrix of the same
transformation $D$ but interpreted under both basis' changes.

Comment: in my commentary below your question I misuse $f$ for $D$